# Replacing white spaces in Sitecore media library links

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore, sitecore6

When W3C validating my page I'm getting these errors:

```
Bad value /~/media/Image Libraries/Carousel Images/sea.jpg?w=652&h=263&bc=transparent&as=1&thn=1 for attribute src on element img: Whitespace in path component. Use %20 in place of spaces.
```

Is there somewhere in the pipelines or such that I alter these links before they're rendered?

**Edit:**

This is an example image tag:

```
<img width="257" height="155" src="/~/media/Image Libraries/Section Pods/headphonewoman.jpg?w=257&h=155&bc=transparent&as=1&thn=1" alt="Administration">
```

And this is the exact error:

```
Error Line 565, Column 218: Bad value /~/media/Image Libraries/Carousel Images/office.jpg?w=652&h=263&bc=transparent&as=1&thn=1 for attribute src on element img: Whitespace in path component. Use %20 in place of spaces.

…ages/office.jpg?w=652&amp;h=263&amp;bc=transparent&amp;as=1&amp;thn=1" />

Syntax of IRI reference:
    Any URL. For example: /hello, #canvas, or http://example.org/. Characters should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as %20.
```

We've also tried adding a pipeline which overrides `GetMediaUrl` in `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider` but that doesn't help.

Comment: List the fragment in context, along with the exact error message.

Answer (score 3):

You can **potentially** do it under the `<encodeNameReplacements>` node of the `web.config`:

```
<encodeNameReplacements>
  // ..
  <replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="%20" />
  // ..
</encodeNameReplacements>
```

Comment: <replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-"/> . This worked for us.